# Case matching on read function in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, switch-statement, record

I am wondering how to check success or failure (resulting in Prelude.read: no parse) of the read function in Haskell. In my case i run "(read formatted :: Int)" in code formatting a record structure, where the fields might be a single Int in String form but might also contain something else. I want to apply my function only to the fields where the read returns an Int. Thanks.

Comment: You could use https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe and pattern match with `case` on the returned `Maybe String`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider `readMaybe` from Text.Read. Once the value is returned within the `Maybe` monad then you can use `case` to decide what to do.

```
import Text.Read

add1 :: String -> Maybe Int
add1 str = case intval of  
   Just x -> Just (x + 1)
   Nothing -> Nothing

   where
      intval = readMaybe str


main = do
   print $ add1 "7"
   print $ add1 "7.0"
```

If you want to be more adventurous, now that the data is in the Maybe monad, we can treat the Maybe as a functor and use applicative functors to process them.

Comment: Proposed simplification: `case readMaybe str of ...` instead of `case intval of ... where intval = readMaybe str`. Maybe you have a subtle reason for naming that; if so, you might want to call it out.